# How to Delete Images from Public/Images Folder in laravel 5 (URL Data)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

how to delete images file from public/images folder in laravel 5 ??

i found some example from this site, but i know they are just using the file name in their `record table`, but i'm using something like `URL` e.g `localhost/project/uploads/filename.jpg` on my `record table`. so if i tried like this :

```
    $image_path = $data->image;  // the value is : localhost/project/image/filename.format
    if(File::exists($image_path)) {
        File::delete($image_path);
    }
```

the file is not deleted

help pls, thanks

Comment: var_dump(File::exists($image_path)) is true or false?

Comment: @AlfredoEM false

Comment: Few things you can try: check if there is some permission issue Or check if actually the file you want to delete exist in that location.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you want to delete image from your server, you have to reference location of file in directory server, means you could not reference by url link to delete it.

Commonly, Laravel 5 file is locate in *public* folder.

Example: your files are located in  *public/images*

```
$image_path = "/images/filename.ext";  // Value is not URL but directory file path
if(File::exists($image_path)) {
    File::delete($image_path);
}
```

If I can delete image from server by reference URL then Google is the first target :)

Comment: ok. i got it, so i just add new field named image_name and that code above working fine... thanks for your explanation by the way :D

Comment: use the `public_path` function as well.

Comment: From where should I import `File`?

Comment: From `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the normal PHP delete file keyword ( @unlink )

```
$image_path = "the name of your image path here/".$request->Image; 

 if (file_exists($image_path)) {

       @unlink($image_path);

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do to delete an image:

```
public function SliderDelete(String $slider_id)
{
    $slider             = Slider::findOrFail($slider_id);
    $image_path         = public_path("\storage\images\sliders\\") .$slider->photo;

    if(File::exists($image_path)) {
        File::delete($image_path);
    }
    else{
        $slider->delete();
        //abort(404);
    }

    $slider->delete();

    return response()->json(['success'=>'Slider deleted successfully!']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in laravel 8 you do it like

```
// import Storage class
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::disk('public')->delete('path-of-file');
```

you can use disk of your choice like

```
Storage::disk('s3')->delete('path-of-file');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $filename = public_path($fileloc);

            if(File::exists($filename)) {
                File::delete($filename);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

call this function and pass two parameter 
$filepath = path where your file exist
$filename = name of your file

```
public static function UnlinkImage($filepath,$fileName)
{
    $old_image = $filepath.$fileName;
    if (file_exists($old_image)) {
       @unlink($old_image);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function destroy($id)
    {   

        $imagePath = YourModelName::select('image')->where('id', $id)->first();

         $filePath = $imagePath->image;

                   if (file_exists($filePath)) {

                   unlink($filePath);

           YourModelName::where('id', $id)->delete();

        }else{

         YourModelName::where('id', $id)->delete();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to delete the image it should be in the following form :
"/uploads/img1.jpg" where uploads directory is in the public directory then use the following code:

```
$image_path = puplic_path("/uploads/img1.jpg")
if (file_exists($image_path)) {
        File::delete($image_path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct and easy way .

```
 if (file_exists(public_path() . '/storage/gallery/images/'. $item->image)) {
                    unlink(public_path() . '/storage/gallery/images/'. $item->image);
}
```