# How to delete multiple image in public/folder when updating in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I save multiple images using array in database. eg. `img.jpg,img1.jpg,img2.jpg` this is my code.

```
$this->validate($request,[
        'listing_id' => 'required',
        'images.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        'description' => 'required',
        'features' => 'required',
        'make' => 'required',
    ]);

    $vehicles = vehicle::find($id);
    $input=$request->all();
    $images=array();
    if($files=$request->File('images')){
        foreach($files as $file){
            $name=date('mdYHis').uniqid().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $file->move('uploaded-images',$name);
            $images[]=$name;
            $vehicles->images = implode(",",$images);
        }
    }else{

        $vehicles->images = $request->images_dummy;

    }
```

I want is to delete the image file in `public/uploaded-images`.
i found this [How to Delete Images from Public/Images Folder in laravel 5 (URL Data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44710894/how-to-delete-images-from-public-images-folder-in-laravel-5-url-data) but its not working in my code.

Comment: So you store a comma separated list of images, and when updating you want to delete all of the images in the comma separated list - is that right?

Comment: yes sir .. i use this when uploading the images `vehicles->images = implode(",",$images);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you store the images as a comma separated list, you just need to explode the string (which produces an array) and then loop over it to delete the images.

Something like this should work:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$images = explode(",", $vehicles->images);

foreach ($image as $images) {
    Storage::delete("uploaded-images/{$image}");
}
```

If you changed your code to store the image names as the actual path to the image (i.e `uploaded-images/img.jpg,uploaded-images/img1.jpg` then you could alter this to be a but simpler:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$images = explode(",", $vehicles->images);
Storage::delete($iamges);
```

Both of these examples can be found in the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#deleting-files).

Comment: `$img = explode(",", $vehicles->images);
        Storage::delete($img);
        
        if($files=$request->File('images')){
            foreach($files as $file){
                $name=('uploaded-images/').date('mdYHis').uniqid().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $file->move('uploaded-images',$name);
                $images[]=$name;
                $vehicles->images = implode(",",$images);
            }
        }else{
            $imagess = $request->images_dummy;
            $vehicles->images = $imagess;

        }`

Comment: i updated my code but still adding images in `uploaded-images`

Comment: Yes, your code still adds images to the uploaded-images folder. First you are deleting the existing images, then you are adding the new ones. Is this not what you wanted?

Comment: yes sir already solved .. i used use `use File;` instead of storage

`foreach(explode(',', $vehicles->images) as $img)   
        { File::delete('uploaded-images/'.$img); }`

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
use File;

$images = explode(",", $vehicles->images);

foreach($images as $image){

   $image_path = public_path().'/images/'.$image;

   if(File::exists($image_path)) {
    File::delete($image_path);
   }
}
```